# phpseclib SSH - Change directory and run script?

Tags: php, ssh, phpseclib

I have script in /home/pi/mydir which I want to execute so first thing I need to do is

```
$ssh->exec('cd mydir');
```

and then

```
$ssh->exec('./script');
```

but it's not working so can anyone help me?

Comment: Probably your webserver doesn't have the rights to execute that script.

Comment: I'm using xampp, so what kind of rights do I need?

Answer (score 5):

```
cd /path/to/directory && your command
```

Temporary solution for me!

Answer (score 5):

use \n :

```
$ssh->exec("cd mydir\n./script");
```

Or create a file `script.sh` (example) and save it in UNIX format:

```
cd mydir
./script
```

And exec this script:

```
$script = file_get_contents("script.sh");
$ssh->exec($script);
```

Answer (score 3):

This is a fundamental limitation in how exec() works. exec() is kinda like...  you open PuTTY, type in `cd mydir`, re-start PuTTY, and then type in `./script`. You wouldn't expect "./script" to be running in "mydir" if you did all that. Yet that's pretty much what exec() does.

And in this case it's not a phpseclib issue - it's more of an SSH issue. exec(), as defined by the SSH specs, just doesn't support that.

More info:

http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/ssh/examples.html#chdir

My recommendation: either use absolute path's or use read() / write().

Good luck!

Comment: Ok I try to use read and write and it's working fine, but there is one issue when I try to run program/script (./video sample/test) script works for like 1 sec and then goes off. Any soloution?

Comment: The logs might provide some insight.. you can get them by doing `define('NET_SSH2_LOGGING', 2);` at the top of your file and then calling `echo '<pre>' . $ssh->getLog() . '</pre>'` at the end. Once you get the logs, post them and we can see what we see.

Comment: Ok I solve my issue by not killing the process, so it was not phpseclib problem. Anyway thanks for help.